# Prove that $\frac{H_1(\Sigma)}{[\alpha_1], \ldots, [\alpha_g], [\beta_1], \ldots, [\beta_g]} \cong H_1(Y)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, low-dimensional-topology, mayer-vietoris-sequence

I am looking at Definition 2.11 in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0101206.pdf.  In particular, given a Heegaard diagram $(\Sigma, \alpha, \beta)$ for a 3-manifold $Y$, how to prove the isomorphism
$$\frac{H_1(\Sigma)}{[\alpha_1], \ldots, [\alpha_g], [\beta_1], \ldots, [\beta_g]} \cong H_1(Y)$$
using Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: Do you know what Mayer-Vietoris sequence is? Did you try to write it down in this case? Where did you get stuck? Edit your question to explain this.

Comment: yes i did write it down.  If we decompose $Y$ into handlebodies with common boudary $\Sigma$, i.e. $H_1 \cup_\Sigma H_2$, i am getting confused looking at the inclusion map $i: \Sigma \to H_j$.  By exactness, it's something like $H_1(H_1)\oplus H_1(H_2)$ modulo the image of $i_*$.  But how do we compute this image of $i_*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the easiest way to see this identity is to view $Y$ as being obtained by taking $\Sigma \times [0,1]$ attaching fattened disks (i.e 3-dimensional 2-handles) to $\Sigma \times \{0\}$ and $\Sigma \times \{1\}$ using the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ respectively. This gives a 3-manifold $\widehat{Y}$ with two spherical boundary components (exercise: see why the Heegaard splitting conditions imply this boundary), which we cap off with two balls to obtain $Y$. Since we are just computing $H_1$ of $Y$ we can ignore the balls and just compute $H_1(\widehat{Y})\cong H_1(Y)$. We can do this using Mayer-Vietoris on the decomposition $\widehat{Y}=\Sigma \times [0,1] \cup \sqcup_{i=1}^{2g} D^2 \times D^1$. Looking at the $H_1$ terms, we obtain a sequence of the form:
$$
H_1( \sqcup_{i=1}^{2g} \partial D^2 \times D^1) \rightarrow H_1 (\Sigma \times [0,1]) \rightarrow H_1(\widehat{Y}) \rightarrow 0
$$
This gives the necessary identity, since the images of $\partial D^2 \times D^1$ are exactly the classes given by the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ in $H_1 (\Sigma \times [0,1])\cong H_1(\Sigma)$.